# How to use scrapy-splash with rotating​ proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I was only successful with scraping js content by using the following as a request

```
def start_requests(self): 
    for url in self.start_urls: 
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url, 
            self.parse, 
            meta={ 'splash': { 'endpoint': 'render.html', 'args': {'wait': 0.5} } }
        )
```

How do i apply both `excute` and 
`render.html` endpoints in the scrapy `request` to use a rotating proxy service while scraping dynamic content?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use both `execute` and `render.html` endpoints, `execute` is more general. Regarding proxy, `execute` endpoint supports `proxy` parameter (see the [documentation](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#execute)) which is either a proxy URL, or a [Proxy Profile](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#proxy-profiles) name.